# Is it ethical to give a hitchiker a ride

Tags: ethics

You are driving in a car and see a woman standing in a bus stop trying to hitchhike.
Is it ethical to give her a lift?
I can think of two reasons against:

1) By giving her a ride, you are actually encouraging her (and maybe others) to hitchhike more. Since hitchhiking can be dangerous (someone might try in the future to kidnap or rape her), you are encouraging her to act in a reckless manner.

2) By giving her a ride, you are decreasing the demand for the local bus / local taxi. Which might lead to abolishing this bus stand, and hurting other potential passengers.

So, could giving a ride be considered morally wrong?

Comment: Ah, but if you don't give her a lift maybe someone else waiting for the bus will rape her? Maybe she's a surgeon trying to get to hospital to perform life saving surgery and the next bus doesn't come for an hour....

Comment: Can you specify the philosophical concern here a bit more clearly? What might you be reading that has made this an important or urgent concern? Can you tell us a little bit more about your context and motivations?

Comment: this hasn't come from reading, rather each time i see a female hitchhiker i have these internal questions; so i thought this forum would be able to pinpoint me to some works that could 'shed some light' on what is 'morally correct'

Comment: it seems that hitchiking itself is against the law in some countries, including local governments in us, china, singapore and honkgong
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitchhiking

and

http://wikitravel.org/en/Tips_for_hitchhiking

Comment: depends on how you define ethics. either of your reason is correct. depends on how you think at the moment and what you choose.

Comment: I think there is a very important factor to this equation that nobody is asking about.  What do you do with the hitchhiker once you have her in your clutches?

Comment: I'm closing at this time pending some clarification of the question. Please consider reformulating to discuss the motivation and concern behind your philosophical concern here. In passing maybe you can formulate this a bit more straightforwardly -- asking us about a specific philosophical concern is definitely better than asking whether a particular action in a particular situation can be considered 'moral' (since this is basically a poll, which is discouraged as per global SE guidelines.)

Answer (score 5):

The answer to almost all questions of the form, "What if I perform some small favor for someone who needs it--is this morally wrong?" is *no*.  Human societies perform better when people perform small favors for each other; it is what one would wish to be the case as a general rule; it is advocated by most every major religion; and so on.  It's very hard to make a compelling case that it's actually *wrong*.

For example, the bus obviously isn't serving *that* woman so well, and she has decided the risks are worth the advantage.  If you think she's made an error, you can talk to her about it, but you can't know in advance.

The converse question, are you morally *required* to help, is also usually answered "no" according to most systems (though it is yes according to some flavors of consequentialism that ignore the consequences of the moral system on the followers given human nature).

Answer (score 5):

There are several misconceptions in the arguments stated in the question.

1) By giving her a ride, you are *not* encouraging her to hitchhike; she's *already* hitchhiking.  In fact, by picking her up, you have the opportunity (if you so desire) to attempt to persuade her of the dangers of hitchhiking.  In short, your action is *not* inciting a moral hazard.

2) By giving her a ride, you are *not* reducing the demand on local transport such as busses and taxis; the value proposition of those services come from a balance of price and convenience.  Hitchhiking (and, for that matter, walking) is simply at the far end of that spectrum: no cost, very inconvenient.

It is possible that there are valid arguments for the immorality of picking up hitchhikers, but these don't come close.